# How to use old value of variable with new value of variable in closed cycle in Openmodellica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I want to adjust the mass flow rate of a pump by using similarities laws so if I want to head and flow rate equation. I need to use old value and new value of head so that I can calculate new value of mass flow rate.

Can anybody tell me how can I write this in program in OpenModellica.

Answer (score 1):

Generally Modelica is not designed to access "old values" of a continuous variable, as this is usually not necessary to model physical behavior. For discrete events there is the `pre()` operator, for clocks `previous()` but none of them is useful in continuous modeling.

What is common in continuous modeling, is to have relations based on the derivative `der()` of a variable, but not "old values". Personally I would double-check if you really need an old value or if that is just a form of abstraction chosen due to limitations of other software...

Still you can use the `delay()` operator as shown below to delay a signal by a fixed or a variable amount of time.

```
model DelayExample
  Real x, y_fix, y_var;
equation 
  x = time;
  y_fix = delay(x, 100e-3);
  y_var = delay(x, min(time/2,0.2), 0.2);
end DelayExample;
```

The result is the following:
[image: Result of DelayExample]

If you want to do use graphical modeling, you can use blocks from `Modelica.Blocks.Nonlinear`, namely

- `Modelica.Blocks.Nonlinear.FixedDelay`
- `Modelica.Blocks.Nonlinear.PadeDelay`
- `Modelica.Blocks.Nonlinear.VariableDelay`

Comment: “Adjusting the flow rate of a pump” sounds like “control” of a device to me? Modelica clearly was designed as a _cyber-physical_ modeling language and what is described by the OP, is the cyber-part of Modelica’s design.

Comment: Controlling a value is for sure possible in Modelica, via continuous or discrete controllers or in other ways. Accessing an "old value" directly is not possible that easily, except for the delay operator which tends to be critical...

Comment: Fair enough. What is “critical” about the delay operator?

Comment: From the top of my head, trying to remember years-old information: (1) It (used to?) have a fixed buffer-size. So if the delay time is big and/or the solver-steps are small, the block can generate errors (depending on model properties). (2) Discontinuities at the input are not output as such, but are "swallowed".